# Create a new word from string on stack in Forth

Tags: forth

I need to use `create` on a string that I got from `parse-name`. Possible? Perhaps using the word `evaluate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a named definition programmatically, you have the following options:

1. allow a defining word to take the name from the input stream;
2. use the well-known word `execute-parsing`;
3. compose a string and pass it to `evaluate`.

#### 1. Using a defining word

If you need to create a word with a name that `parse-name` returns, just use a usual defining word instead of `parse-name`.

```
: foo ( "name" -- ) create  123 , ;
foo bar \ it creates "bar"
bar @ . \ it prints "123"
```

#### 2. Using `execute-parsing`

There is a well-known word `execute-parsing ( i*x c-addr u xt -- j*x )`, which is provided by some systems, or can be loaded from a standard-compliant library, such as [execute-parsing.fs](https://theforth.net/package/compat/current-view/execute-parsing.fs).

This word executes given xt providing the given string as the input buffer. This word can be useful when you compose a name programmatically.

```
: foo ( "name" -- )
  parse-name
  ['] create execute-parsing
  123 ,
;
```

#### 3. Composing a string

The standard means to compose a string are too low-level: you allocate a memory region and place sub-strings using `move ( addr.src addr.dest u.length -- )`. Therefore, a better way is to use some library (for example, [ffl/str.fs](https://irdvo.nl/FFL/docs/str.html)).

Another way to compose a *short* string is to use the **pictured numeric output** mechanism and the [word](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/HOLDS) `holds ( c-addr u -- )`:

```
: foo ( "name" -- )
  <#  parse-name holds  s" create " holds   0 0 #>
  evaluate
  123 ,
;
```

In this mechanism, the new sub-string prepends the previous one (i.e., they are placed into the buffer from right to left).

The available buffer size can be [obtained](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#usage:env) by:

```
s" /HOLD" environment? 0= throw .
```

The string returned by [`#> ( xd -- c-addr u )`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/num-end) is [transient](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#usage:transient).

When you use `evaluate`, you must be sure that all names will be resolved correctly (due to late binding).

Comment: Someone recommended using `>IN`. Any comments on that?

Comment: The [variable `>in`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/toIN) allows to rewind the input buffer (the parse area). It's nothing to do with creating a word programmatically. It's sometimes used in a user-define interpreter (for lookahead), or when you need to resolve a name from the parse area before defining a new word with the same name from the parse area.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
s" create " parse-name foo $+ evaluate
```